# Can I "wear an umbrella"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

Does it make sense to say the following?

> Yesterday I wore an umbrella and a coat.

Comment: "Can I wear an umbrella?" Erm...ok, if you really want to. You might look pretty stupid though.

Comment: @Urbycoz http://www.diylife.com/2007/10/01/make-a-bat-costume-with-an-umbrella/

Comment: Sure you can: http://www.umbrellahat.net/

Comment: You can certainly wear one out.

Comment: It's grammatical, doesn't literally make sense, but might be said by some people.

Comment: I think he wants to know, if one has an umbrella in his hand which verb should we use? he is wearing an umbrella, holding an umbrella, ....

Comment: I would certainly say "I wore an umbrella and coat" rather than "I wore a coat and carried an umbrella". Don't let anyone give you crap about it, English is a beautifully expressive language, and it would merely sound "British" of you to say something like this, to the ears of a Yank. How it sounds to the ears of a Brit I have no idea, altho likely "like the braying of a donkey" I'm sure ;-)

Comment: Yesterday, I **donned** my umbrella and coat.

Comment: I might point out that 'wear' and 'use' are often problematic for L2 users of English as they translate confusingly to a number of languages. My most immediate example is the Indonesian *pakai* which serves as both, but I know this to be true in other languages as well. Fun fact: another common confusion of the same brand is *turn on* and *open*.

Comment: @earthmeLon, Actually that doesn't make it any better. It's just as weird to use "don" for umbrellas.

Answer (score 89):

Yes. You can wear an umbrella. You can even give a seductive demonic grin when doing so.

[image: Hot umbrella]

I see no reason she could not also be wearing a coat, other than perhaps selling fewer umbrellas for others to wear.

Silly me, someone requested a picture of how you carry an umbrella. I carry mine like this (also with a coat to further illustrate the scenario),

[image: How to carry an umbrella like a boss.]

Comment: oh come on people, this answer is amusing but not helpful in answering the original question, don't vote it to the top

Comment: It *is* helpful in that it makes a distinction of *how* an umbrella would be worn. I do think that it should contain information about how people typically **carry** umbrellas (amusing images welcome).

Comment: The first picture raises in my mind a second question: Does a sexy figure and come-on look outweigh really stupid looking attire? I think the answer is no, but it's debateable.

Comment: +1 for the humor, and yes, technically you can wear an umbrella.  I had a prof in college that wore an umbrella on his head.  He was bald & always said "It's not so much the wet as it is the noise"

Comment: @jhocking: This answer does, technically, answer the question.  What it fails to point out is that "wear" is not the *usual* verb to describe using an umbrella.

Comment: @Dan: Or maybe it does – indirectly. My first thought was "This _has_ to be photoshopped," but then I realized, [it isn't](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1455&bih=776&q=umbrella+hat). Incidentally, I also learned that this look has been around for a [long time](http://blogs.sos.wa.gov/FromOurCorner/index.php/2010/02/photo-of-the-day/).

Comment: @jhocking When you tell people to don't do something it's like telling them to do it, just look at the votes of this answer.

Comment: Love the pictures.

Answer (score 80):

It doesn't make sense in English. You wear a coat and carry an umbrella.

Comment: Not the same thing. "Alexander McQueen" is a metonym for Alexander McQueen-branded clothing. On the other hand, the original declaration is not an instance of metonymy; it's nonsense (except in the literal case of a wearable umbrella as pictured above).

Comment: You can most certainly wear an umbrella, just as you would wear a sword. I've seen plenty of people do so. How absurd to think you can't wear an umbrella.

Comment: @jcolebrand asked how it sounds to the ears of a Brit. Well, it doesn't make sense. You wear something attached to the body (a sword on a belt, a gun in a holster, a sandwich-board over the shoulders...); you carry something which will get lost if you let go of it. Perhaps American usage is different -- although another comment suggests that saying "wear an umbrella" sounds odd. The point I was making is that some languages do use the same word for both *wear* and *carry* -- French, for example, has *porter*. English has two distinct words for two distinct actions.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, that was rather my point. It sounds foreign, but not too foreign, like "this shouldn't make sense to me, but it must make sense to someone". Anyways, I think the phrase is poetic enough to be accurate. (Also: braying of a donkey :p)

Comment: "English has two distinct words for two distinct actions" -- or more precisely, English has two distinct words for a multitude of distinct actions, that we choose to collect into two groups for ease of reference but that other languages collect in one group, also for ease of reference ;-)

Answer (score 52):

In usual parlance, an umbrella is carried, not worn; but fashion circles speak of wearing an umbrella, when it dominates the get-up.  For example, a 2011 [manrepeller.com](http://www.manrepeller.com/2011/05/that-time-i-wore-umbrella-indoors.html) blog entry called "That Time I Wore an Umbrella Indoors" says a recent night "will forever be known (to me, at least) as the night I wore–not held–an umbrella in doors", and fotoblur.com [image 91796](http://www.fotoblur.com/images/91796) is titled "she wore a red umbrella".  A 2011 [kandeej.com](http://www.kandeej.com/2011/10/diy-3-way-to-wear-umbrella.html) blog entry titled "DIY: 3 way to 'wear' an umbrella" is about wearing part of an umbrella (its canopy) as an accessory.

Answer (score 33):

I generally use the verbs ***carry, bring,*** or ***take*** to refer to the situation when I take it with me *in case of rain*.

> *It looked like rain this morning so I brought my umbrella.*

Then when it starts raining I ***use*** my umbrella.

> *It was really raining hard yesterday, so I had to use my umbrella.*

Comment: Unless there are two people sharing it, in which case you [**employ**](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/hollies/busstop.html) the umbrella. :^)

Answer (score 14):

An umbrella is usually carried.  The difference between wearing something and carrying it is that carried items are attached to the body and are not being held in a hand or otherwise.
For instance we wear clothing or jewelry because they stay on.  If we were to have a ring in the palm of our hand we would be carrying it.
So to wear an umbrella would indicate to have it attached to the body.  The answers with the umbrella hat shows this. Also having it slung through a belt loop could be called wearing it.
In use without a weird gadget it could not be worn

Comment: Striking it through one's waist belt would most certainly count as wearing it.

Comment: @jcolebrand: So would placing it on your head like a hat, it does not take away the absurdity of the phrase. You could wear an umbrella on your belt, as you wear a sword in its scabbard, but only the inference of "wearing an umbrella" is a  literal one, outside of that usage, it is nonsense.

Comment: BTW wearing a sword is not correct either really, it is worn at a location (worn on the hip/worn on the belt/etc) - it is simply a historical short hand that has become accepted over time. Even a hat is worn on the head. We do not need to say "I am wearing trousers on my legs", clothing is wearable - most other things are only wearable given a location that describes how it can be worn ("hat on my head" etc)

Answer (score 11):

[Wear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wear) - to carry or have on the body or about the person as a covering, equipment, ornament, or the like.

So yes you can wear an umbrella

Comment: He meant in typical parlance do a significant amount of people (say  >5% of population) say that.

Answer (score 8):

I very much agree with the other answers. Though, a *child* (subclass(?)) of the umbrella is a the *nubrella* (and I suppose Umbrella Hat falls under that category as well). And that, I believe you very much can wear. So you can *wear some* umbrellas, but not all. And I suppose it also depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

You wear raincoat or coat, but you carry umbrella. Another example we don't wear gun, but rather carry it. Although if you hold the coat in your hands the verb is carry too.

Comment: Though you do wear a holster, and I occasionally hear people say they are "wearing a gun" meaning that they are carrying a gun in a holster. And when googling this, I came across this page: http://www.girlsheartguns.com/?page_id=541 with the wonderful title, "What to Wear to a Shooting Range". I must admit that, as a man, I never really considered what constituted fasionable shooting-range wear.